# Why are my entry changes not appearing on my live website

Tags: 404-page

When I move/add/edit my pages they are appearing on live preview, but when I search my website manually on a they are not there.

Comment: Are you using caching anywhere on the site? You could be seeing a stale cached version of the page.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.